# MySQL Query with Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

```
Table: UserInfoTbl
=======================
| username  | type    |
=======================
| user0001  | premium |
| user0002  | premium |
| user0003  | normal  |
| user0004  | premium |
=======================

Table: UserPvTbl
========================
| username | fUsername |
========================
| user0003 | user0002  |
| user0002 | user0001  |
| user0003 | user0001  |
========================
```

How can I select all the information from UserInfoTbl where fUsername of UserPvTbl has username of user0003?

Edit: Meaning that I need to retrieve information of user0002 and user0001 from the UserInfoTbl

Edit2: Relationship between both tables : UserInfoTbl.username = UserPvTbl.username

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DroidMatt can you clarify what the 2 tables relationship are

UserInfoTbl.username  = UserPvTbl.fusername
or
UserInfoTbl.username  = UserPvTbl.username

Vikram is right assuming the first. otherwise you want this.

```
SELECT *
FROM UserInfoTbl, UserPvTbl
WHERE UserPvTbl.username = UserInfoTbl.username
AND UserPvTbl.username = 'user0003'
```

Comment: UserInfoTbl.username = UserPvTbl.username  is the correct one. Sorry I forgot to clarify the relationship.

Comment: Note: Vikram just renamed/shortened the table names.
UserInfoTbl = U and UserPvTbl = UP

Answer (score 1):

Use like :

```
select * from UserInfoTbl inner join UserPvTbl on UserInfoTbl.username=UserPvTbl.fusename
where UserPvTbl.usename='user0003'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select U.*
from UserInfoTbl U
inner join UserPvTbl UP
on U.username  = UP.fusername  
where UP.username = 'user0003'
```

Comment: Hello Vikram. 
Do you mind to explain on U.* , UP and 'from UserInfoTbl U'? Im kinda lost here.

Comment: U is short name for `UserInfoTbl`, UP for `UserPvTbl` and U.* will return all the column of `UserInfoTbl`